# Create active copy of VendInvoiceInfoTable and VendInvoiceInfoLines

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm trying to modify VendInvoiceInfoTable and VendInvoiceInfoLines, and some related data, by code.

I need to create the working copy of those tables (a copy with a ParmId set) so that I can make my changes before copying back, as the GUI does.

Is this possible using PurchFormLetter? It seems as though it should be.

```
//Create Copy
PurchFormLetter_Invoice purhFormLetter_Invoice;
//***do stuff in here?***

//Make changes
activeVendInvoiceInfoTable.MyField = "Hey I have changed";
activeVendInvoiceInfoTable.Update();

//Copy back to saved
VendInvoiceInfoTable::moveFromActiveToSaved(activeVendInvoiceInfoTable);
```

So the question is how do I create my `activeVendInvoiceInfoTable` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The Purchformletter Classes are for posting Invoices, Packingslips, Conformations etc.
I don't now exactly, what you want to achieve, so I provied different Solutions.
First you can take a look, how AX handles Proforma Invoices, there you can see, that ax posts the invoice in a Transaction an at last abort the whole Transaction with a ttsabort.

Another thing that may fit for your needs, is to make a temporary copy of the table. I wrote some code to be more specific: There I make a normal table temporary and modify some data before coping it back and write it to the database.

```
static void Job6(Args _args)
{
    VendInvoiceInfoLine vendInvoiceInfoLine;
    VendInvoiceInfoLine vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp;
    RecId localRecId;
    ;


    select firstOnly vendInvoiceInfoLine;
    localRecId = vendInvoiceInfoLine.RecId;

    vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp.setTmp();

    vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp.data(vendInvoiceInfoLine);

    info(strFmt("Copy of vendInvoiceInfoLine %1",vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp.ItemId));

    //Modifiy whatever
    vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp.ItemId = "HelloWorld";
    vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp.insert();


    info(strFmt("Orig of vendInvoiceInfoLine %1",vendInvoiceInfoLine.ItemId));
    info(strFmt("Copy of vendInvoiceInfoLine %1",vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp.ItemId));


    //Write Back
    ttsBegin;
    select forUpdate vendInvoiceInfoLine where vendInvoiceInfoLine.RecId == localRecId;

    vendInvoiceInfoLine.data(vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp);
    vendInvoiceInfoLine.update();
    ttsCommit;

    info(strFmt("Orig of vendInvoiceInfoLine %1",vendInvoiceInfoLine.ItemId));
    info(strFmt("Copy of vendInvoiceInfoLine %1",vendInvoiceInfoLinetmp.ItemId));

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate standard, as in when in use the ParmId is populated, taken from PurchParmUpdate. The standard forms for Viewing VendInvoiceInfoTable and VendInvoiceInfoLine use the PurchFormLetter framework to do everything. See for example VendEditInvoice form called form SalesFormLEtter_ApprovalJournal. If the ParmId isn't set there is a risk a user can open the invoice and overwrite our changes.